# PySide6.QtTest.QTest.mouseClick() - not exposed - is it not meant to be used?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I got the code below from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61213729/simulate-the-click-on-a-button-in-the-pyqt5-qmessagebox-widget-during-unittest)

In the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtTest/QTest.html), `mouseClick` is not listed but it's present in `QtTest.py` and usable.

Does that mean it's deprecated?

```
import sys

import unittest
import threading

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest


class Fortest:
    def messagebox(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg.setText("message text")
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Close)
        msg.buttonClicked.connect(msg.close)
        msg.exec_()


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def testMessagebox(self):
        a = Fortest()
        threading.Timer(1, self.execute_click).start()
        a.messagebox()

    def execute_click(self):
        w = QApplication.activeWindow()
        if isinstance(w, QMessageBox):
            close_button = w.button(QMessageBox.Close)
            QTest.mouseClick(close_button, Qt.LeftButton)
```

Comment: I believe it is not obsolete.
Because in PySide6 documentation QTest is presented, https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtTest/index.html.

Comment: @JonasVieiradeSouza The OP is asking about the `mouseClick()` function, not the QTest namespace.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the PySide docs for anything, since they're auto-generated (badly) from the Qt docs. If you want to know the true APIs, execute `help(QtTest.QTest)` in a python interactive session.